# Suggestions for algebraic function fields papers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

My professor of algebraic function fields class gave me a paper to make a project (give the proof details, fill some gaps, etc). As my previous question here suggests, the paper he gave me is hard for me. He says if I know another paper to work, it's ok. He is very busy and he doesn't care about me and leaves me to find another one.

My background:

> I finished [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).
>
> I finished the third chapter of [Stichtenoth's Algebraic function
>   fields and codes](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=IE73Tew7cTMC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0).

I've heard that if we finish the third chapter of Stichtenoth's book we're prepared to make some research in the area.

However, as I said my ambition is much lower, is there some paper which I can read by myself with ONLY this background? I need some suggestions.

I don't know if I have many choices, so ANY paper following these criteria not so old, it would be great, really.

I hope not asking so much, I really need help, you're my last chance.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Are you (or your professor) interested in stuff from the coding theory side? Many papers rely on material from Chapter V (Hasse-Weil) and are looking for curves of a fixed genus with many points. Papers on decoding algorithms may be accessible to you. Tom Hoholdt (IIRC) has written a nice exposition on Feng-Rao algorithm, which probably doesn't really need the material from Stichtenoth's Chapter VI even though it is related.

Comment: Chapter III should be enough for you to calculate the genus of curves coming from a Witt vector equations. Such calculations were underlying the Shanbhag-Kumar-Helleseth bounds on character sums over Galois rings. I don't think that has ever been written (in that form) in a published paper. I could outline that as an extra credit problem for you. Do check with your professor that it would be ok for you to: A) familiarize yourself with Witt vector arithmetic and B) calculate the genus of certain towers of Artin-Schreier extensions related to this area. You will need Hilbert's different formula.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen First of all, thank you for your comments. Do you have some references for items A and B?

Comment: I learned about Witt vectors from Jacobson's Basic Algebra II, chapter 8.10. I wanted to publish my results on certain character sums over Galois rings of characteristic four with the theory in B). My colleagues were faster, so I never got to publishing it. All I have is handwritten seminar notes (and a long lost 1-page abstract). The set up is a family of Galois extensions of the rational function field $\Bbb{F}_2(x)$ such that the Galois group is cyclic of order 4, 8, 16,... The case where all the ramification takes place above the infinite point is interesting enough for the applications.

Comment: BTW the stuff about character sums over Galois rings is from the 90s. Don't know if that is "not so old".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen no, this is not so old. Certainly I will take your comments in consideration, the only problem is I think it would be easier for me if this subject had some published paper which I could work over.

Comment: @user42912 Since you've read the first three chapters, could you please tell me what are the prerequisites to start reading the book "Algebraic function fields and codes" written by Stichtenoth?

Comment: @rfloc you don’t need any prerequisite to read this book